# Exit bash script if a command succeeds

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

I have some simple smoke test scripts that generally look like:

```
set -e

run-command
run-other-command

echo ok
```

This works great when I expect commands to succeed; if any fails, the `set -e` will exit the script early with a non-zero exit code.

However sometimes I expect a command to fail, and I want the script to exit otherwise (that is, if the command exits with code 0). I would have thought I could just write:

```
set -e
run-command-that-succeeds
! run-command-that-fails
```

But this ignores the exit code. The bash man page says this about `set -e`:

> The shell does not exit [...] if the command's return value is being inverted with !

Alternatives that work are:

```
set -e
! run-command-that-fails
[[ $? -eq 0 ]]
```

and

```
set -e
if run-command-that-fails; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Are these the best options, or is there a more idiomatic alternative to exit if a command succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tests indicate that `(! run-command-that-fails)` is a solution. This runs `run-command-that-fails` in a subshell.

If you need to run `run-command-that-fails` in the main shell for whatever reason, then you need another solution. I notice that `{ ! run-command-that-fails; }` is *not* a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you dropped the `set -e` completely and instead used something like

```bsh
should-fail    && exit 1
should-succeed || exit 1
```

In the above code, the `should-fail` is expected to fail, and if it fails to do that, the script exits with a non-zero exit code.

The second one is expected to succeed, and the script exits if it doesn't.

Or, if you want consistency in the use of AND-OR-lists,

```bsh
! should-fail  || exit 1
should-succeed || exit 1
```

or

```
should-fail      && exit 1
! should-succeed && exit 1
```

For anything that requires more than a simple `exit` if it fails, I would use

```bsh
if should-fail; then
    # handle failure in test
    exit 1
fi

if ! should-succeed; then
    # handle failure in test
    exit 1
fi
```

As you already noticed, with `set -e` active, the shell does not exit if a command's exit-status is inverted by `!`.  This is a requirement by POSIX.  The following is from [the POSIX specification for the special built-in utility `set`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set), with my emphasis:

> The `-e` setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the `while`, `until`, `if`, or `elif` reserved word, **a pipeline beginning with the `!` reserved word**, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last.